pgxn install isn't honoring --pg_config
I'm trying to install a Postgres extension (h3) with pgxn. I have three versions of Postgres installed on my machine via Postgres.app: 15, 16, and 17. I would like to install h3 in the 15 database. The command I used was:
pgxn install --pg_config /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/bin/pg_config h3

When the install command is running, I see that it's installing into the 17 database instead. Here's an line from the logs that seems telling:
-- Found PostgreSQL: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/17/lib/libpq.dylib (found version "17.1")  missing components: PostGIS

I've triple-checked that the path I specified for --pg_config exists. Does anyone know why pgxn might be picking up the wrong version, or how else I can troubleshoot this?

From here CLI tools did you follow instructions in Configure your $PATH section?

@AdrianKlaver I did put Postgres.app on my PATH when I installed it. The way I understood the pgxn docs, though, it sounded like --pg_config should take precedence over that...


Yes, but did you follow the instructions at the link in my previous comment? 2) Where did the 17 install of Postgres come from?



yes, I followed those instructions; 2) Postgres.app contains multiple versions of Postgres: at present, 15, 16, and 17


The only thing I can of is to add the --sudo option. If that does not work then I would suggest filing an issue here pgxnclient issues.
